# shared written lanaguage, different spoken languages

Tags: sociolinguistics

is there a name for the situation where a group of people share a common written language but speak different languages like with chinese.
e.g. they can read the same newspapers but if they read out the text they would be pronounced differently.kind of the opposite to a synchronic digraphia.
are there any others apart from chinese?

Comment: That's only vaguely true in the case of Chinese. The different topolects of Chinese are really different languages, and their grammar is not identical, so while you can read out a Putonghua text in Cantonese, for example, it is not usually natural Cantonese. I don't know a name for this - the inverse case is 'digraphia'.

Comment: Arabic is somewhat in this situation. However, from what I know the situation is somewhat as Colin Fine has noted for Chinese: what's written will not be the same as natural spontaneous spoken language, even when it is read out loud. This is usually called diglossia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual term for this is [diglossia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diglossia), a word that seems to have first been used for this purpose in Greek to refer to the distinction between the spoken Demotic language and the literary Khatharevousa. The linked Wikipedia article provides several examples, but the one I'm most familiar with is Arabic -- there are many regional spoken varieties that are different enough in phonology and grammar as to form several mutually unintelligible groups, but the written form, so-called "Modern Standard Arabic" (MSA), is less divergent as it tends to be standardized in a form close to Classical and Qur'anic Arabic, and is considered one language. People do also use MSA in some spoken contexts, like reading aloud, speeches or news reports, and many higher-register words used in all contexts in the spoken languages are spoken with an approximation of the MSA phonemes rather than having the form one would expect from the regular sound changes that occurred in everyday words.